# python-vlc find current playing audio

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I want know to which audio is currently playing in my playlist.

eg: it's path, title or index position

```
import vlc

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_list_player_new()
player.set_playback_mode(vlc.PlaybackMode.loop)
songs = ['music1.mp3', 'music2.mp3', 'music.mp3']
media_list = instance.media_list_new(songs)
player.set_media_list(media_list)
player.play_item_at_index(1)
```

I tried bunch of methods unfortunately none of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

Actually the instance is inherited from the `get_media_player` && `get_media` using this you can find current playing song base path.

```
import vlc

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_list_player_new()
player.set_playback_mode(vlc.PlaybackMode.loop)
songs = ['music1.mp3', 'music2.mp3', 'music.mp3']
media_list = instance.media_list_new(songs)
player.set_media_list(media_list)
player.play_item_at_index(1)

player.get_media_player().get_media().get_mrl() # will return path of current playing mp3 or mp4
```